# Save a hash to a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash, strong-parameters

I would like to save the params from the form submitted into a hash called: `hash_options` which corresponds to a field in my table.

1. How do I store the hash of: `hash_options` as the value for: `hash_fields` ?

   - `hash_fields` is a text field and I am trying to store `hash_options` in this row as a plain hash.

---

```
def person_params
  hash_options = {age: params['person']['age'], location: params['person']['location'], gender: params['person']['gender']}
  params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :owner, hash_fields: [hash_options])
end
```

*Side question:* How does the model access and store the params?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to be able to save the hash as is to the database you have a couple of options:

1. If you are using MongoDB(mongoid) you can just define it as a hash type field in your model with:

   `field options_hash, type: Hash`
2. You can use postgresql HStore to save schemaless data into that column which enables you to save the hash into the column and work with it as a Hash.

As for the params part there is no need to include it in the permit call, you can just do:

```
model = Model.new(person_params) do |m|
  m.options_hash = hash_options
end

model.save
```

Comment: I am using postgres. I'm going to expirement with this and get back to you. Thanks.